# dashed line using extCreatePen not printing in Delphi

Tags: delphi, line

I am trying to draw a line using a user-defined pen Style but the line prints straight. am using Delphi Tokyo

```
var
  LLogBrush : tLogBrush;
  LUserstyle : array[0..3] of Double;
begin

  LUserstyle[0]:= 8;
  LUserstyle[1]:= 4;
  LUserstyle[2]:= 8;
  LUserstyle[3]:= 4;

  LLogBrush.lbStyle := BS_Solid;
  LLogBrush.lbColor := Color;
  LLogBrush.lbHatch := 0;

  PaintBox1.Canvas.Pen.Handle := ExtCreatePen(PS_GEOMETRIC or PS_USERSTYLE,
                    2, LLogBrush, 4, @LUserstyle);

  PaintBox1.Canvas.MoveTo(10,10);
  PaintBox1.Canvas.LineTo(100,100);
end;
```

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are ;) The `LUserStyle` array should be an `array of DWORD`, not of `Double`.

Comment: Somebody voted this question down without leaving a comment why he did that. I can't see any reason for a down vote. It's clearly phrased, contains a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and shows that he has done some research himself. So why was it down voted?

Comment: Thanks a lot Tom!